# The limit of a contractive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my book I have the exercise to find a limit of sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-2}+x_{n-1}).$ I don't understand the solution. So I have to prove that this sequence is contractive and it follows the sequence is Cauchy and therefore is convergent. I can do it it's ok. But I have a problem, with finding the limit.

We define $L:=x_2-x_1$

The book says, that I have to show,that $x_{2n+1}=x_1+\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{2^3}+\frac{L}{2^5}+...+ \frac{L}{2^{2n-1}}$, whence the $lim(x_n)=\frac{2}{3}L$.

I don't understand why $x_{2n+1}=x_1+\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{2^3}+\frac{L}{2^5}+...+ \frac{L}{2^{2n-1}}$, because I don't get $x_1$ with my calculations and why this geometric sum $x_1+\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{2^3}+\frac{L}{2^5}+...+ \frac{L}{2^{2n-1}}=\frac{2}{3}L$ even wolframalpha doesn't give me such a simple expression. I will be very grateful if somebody explain me this. It's would be very helpful for my understanding!

Comment: Try calculating the value of $x_{3}$ by using $L$ and then a few more terms. Once you see the pattern then apply induction to prove for general $n$. As for the geometric sum, it directly follows from the formula . $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}x^{r}\,,|x|<1$. Otherwise you can directly google how to solve linear reccurence relations and use the auxiliary equation method.

Comment: Try factoring out $L/2$ then using the geometric series identity.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove this by induction, but to do this we also need a expression for $x_{2n}$. Writing out the first few terms, we conjecture that for $n\geq 1$, we have :
\begin{gather}
 x_{2n} = x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n-1}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}} + \frac{L}{2^{2n-2}} \\
 x_{2n+1} = x_1  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}}
\end{gather}

Let us prove this by induction. We have $x_{3} = \frac 12 (x_1+ x_2) = x_1 + \frac L2$ and $x_{2} = x_1 + L$ .

Assume that both formula hold for a given $n\geq 1$. Then, we have :
\begin{align}
x_{2n+2} &= \frac 12 (x_{2n} +x_{2n+1}) \\
&=\frac 12 \left(x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n-1}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}} + \frac{L}{2^{2n-2}}  + x_1  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}}\right)\\
&= x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n-1} \frac L{2^{2k-1}} + \frac L{2^{2n-1}} +\frac{L}{2^{2n}}\\
&=x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n} \frac L{2^{2k-1}}  +\frac{L}{2^{2n}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
x_{2n+3} &= \frac 12 (x_{2n+1} + x_{2n+2}) \\
&= \frac 12 \left(  x_1  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}} + x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n} \frac L{2^{2k-1}}  +\frac{L}{2^{2n}}\right) \\
&= x_1  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}} + \frac L{2^{2n+1}} \\
&= x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{L}{2^{2k-1}}
\end{align}

By induction, we see that the result holds for all $n\geq 1$. Then, using the formula to comput geometric sums, we get :
$$x_{2n+1} = x_1 + L\frac{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{4}} \to x_1 + \frac{2L}3$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to say you, that thanks to such people like you, I love this world ))